# unable to filter by metric (comparisonValue not recongnized in the 400 value

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api

I am trying to filter my GA api V4 in python by removing pageviews under 200 in my request...
surprisingly, as i follow exactly the syntax of the documentation, i get an error message :

```
>  "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "comparisonValue" at 'report_req
uests[0].metric_filter_clauses[0].filters[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.". Details: "[{'
@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'report_requests[0].metric_f
ilter_clauses[0].filters[0]', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "comparisonValue" at 
\'report_requests[0].metric_filter_clauses[0].filters[0]\': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.'}]
}]"
```

obviously there is a problem in my coding, but I cannot understand what it is : it is a copy paste of the documentation in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#filtering...
is there a difference between the JSON POST from documentation and the one in the batch get from python?
here is the part where I build my request the problematic filter is at the end...:

```
 return analytics.reports().batchGet(
     body={
       'reportRequests': [
        {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2021-07-20', 'endDate': '2021-07-27'}],
            'metrics': [
                {
                    'expression': 'ga:sessions',
                    'expression': 'ga:pageviews'
                    }],
            'dimensions': [
                {
                    'name': 'ga:pagePath'
                    }],
            'orderBys': [
                {
                    'orderType': 'VALUE',
                    'sortOrder': "DESCENDING",
                    'fieldName': 'ga:pageviews'
                    }],
            'dimensionFilterClauses': [
                {
                    'filters': [
                        {
                            'dimensionName':'ga:country',
                            'operator':'BEGINS_WITH',
                            'expressions':['fra']
                            }],
                    }],
            'metricFilterClauses': [
                {
                    'filters': [
                        {
                            'metricName':'ga:pageviews',
                            'operator':'GREATER_THAN',
                            'comparisonValue':['200']                                                          
                            }]
                    }]
            }]
      }
).execute()
```

any idea why it don't work?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Jacques,

`comparisonValue` field value should be a string, not a list, e.g. `'200'` instead of `['200']`.

A good way to eliminate possible coding issues is to test your query directly using the [Google Analytics API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?apix=true).